# How to enhance a dynamically created Jquery Mobile checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox, render

I'm struggling to get this to work:

```
var selectorBox = $('<label for="'+selectorID+'"><input type="checkbox" id="'+selectorID+'" name="'+selectorID+'" class="selector" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext"></label>').trigger('create'),
    cell = $( "<th class='persist essential notxtchkbx rowHigh' "+rowSpanner+"></th>" ).append( selectorBox );

currentRow.prepend( cell );
```

`selectorBox` is the checkbox HTML, which I'm trying to enhance by `trigger("create")` before creating a cell and inserting this cell in a table row.

**Question**:
How do I get this checkbox to render properly?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I can't see what you are trying to achieve with `.trigger('create')`. In the absence of a 'create' event, this will do nothing at all.

Comment: Just got it to work. I need to call `trigger("create")` on the parent element. In my case the TH cell. Calling it directly on the checkbox does not work.

Comment: Then post the answer below ;), not in the comments.

Comment: give me a few mins. Writing it up in the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enhance a checkbox you will need to call `trigger("create")` on its **parent element**. Calling it directly on the checkbox does not work. Just use something like:

```
$("input.myCheckbox").closest("div").trigger("create");
```

And it should work.